# Get the date when an item's quanity changes from zero to non-zero

Tags: mysql

I am trying to construct a query to update a table with the date when an item is received.  The quantity will go from zero to a non-zero number.  We store records every day of every item that is in our system.

So far I have

```
   SELECT dw1.system_id, dw1.item, dw2.date
    FROM dw_inventory_detail dw1
    INNER JOIN dw_inventory_detail dw2 ON dw2.item = dw1.item AND  dw2.system_id = dw1.system_id AND dw1.quantity != dw2.quantity 
    WHERE dw1.system_id = '010000'
    AND dw1.item = 'AGRS'
    AND dw1.quantity = 0
```

This gives me

- 010000    AGRS    2013-03-27
- 010000    AGRS    2013-03-28
- 010000    AGRS    2013-03-29
- 010000    AGRS    2013-03-30
- 010000    AGRS    2013-03-31
- 010000    AGRS    2013-04-01
- 010000    AGRS    2013-04-14
- 010000    AGRS    2013-04-15
- 010000    AGRS    2013-04-16
- 010000    AGRS    2013-04-17

Which is almost correct, but it gives me a row every time the quantity changes.  I only need the date when the quanity goes from zero to non-zero.

I haven't started the update portion of the query yet.  I need to get this part working first.

Original Data looks like this

- 2013-03-27    010000  AGRS        1200
- 2013-03-28    010000  AGRS        1200
- 2013-03-29    010000  AGRS        400
- 2013-03-30    010000  AGRS        400
- 2013-03-31    010000  AGRS        400
- 2013-04-01    010000  AGRS        400
- 2013-04-02    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-03    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-04    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-05    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-06    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-07    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-08    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-09    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-10    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-11    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-12    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-13    010000  AGRS        0
- 2013-04-14    010000  AGRS        3200
- 2013-04-15    010000  AGRS        3200

Comment: Telling us 'what you get' without telling us 'what you have' is deranged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT dw1.system_id, dw1.item, dw2.date
    FROM dw_inventory_detail dw1
    INNER JOIN dw_inventory_detail dw2 ON dw2.item = dw1.item 
    AND  dw2.system_id = dw1.system_id 
    AND dw1.quantity != dw2.quantity 
    AND (dw1.quantity = 0 OR dw2.quantity = 0)
    WHERE dw1.system_id = '010000'
    AND dw1.item = 'AGRS'
```

Note added `AND (dw1.quantity = 0 OR dw2.quantity = 0)`

Comment: That's almost what I need.  It gives me a better start point.  Thanks.